# Selecionar 'select' através do Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, navegador-de-internet, html-select

Preciso selecionar um valor dentro de um `<select>`, porém não estou conseguindo... Já fiz uma vez essa mesma função de selecionar um valor em um `<select>` mas dessa vez não estou conseguindo fazer essa seleção.

Segue o código:

```
await page.waitForSelector('#form-clientes\:contrato') //return is not a valid selector
await page.select('#form-clientes\:contrato', '0000000')
```

O próprio seletor do campo vem com esse `\:`, o ID é `#form-control:contrato`

Tentei também usando `page.evaluate(() => {})` porém não deu certo.

O erro retornado é sempre esse

```
Error é: Error: Evaluation failed: DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#form-clientes:contrato' is not a valid selector.
    at predicate (eval at waitForPredicatePageFunction (:2:21), <anonymous>:6:20)
    at eval (eval at waitForPredicatePageFunction (:2:21), <anonymous>:25:7)
    at pollMutation (__puppeteer_evaluation_script__:17:31)
    at waitForPredicatePageFunction (__puppeteer_evaluation_script__:9:18)
```

Comment: Use duas barras no seletor `'#form-clientes\\:contrato'`

Answer (score 1):

Tu pode usar o evaluate pra fazer esse processo.

Existe uma extenção do chrome que te da o valor do seletor css, isso de uma maneira mais rapida, o [copy-css-selector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copy-css-selector/kemkenbgbgodoglfkkejbdcpojnodnkg) ele irá adicionar o campo Css Path ao seu DevTools.
depois de saber o seletor exato, tu pode fazer selecionar dessa maneira:

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
      document.querySelector("input#form-clientes").value = 1;
}).catch(error => { console.log(error) });
```

pode até pegar algum valor que tu queira, por exemplo:

```
var valorTeste = "nome";

await page.evaluate((valorTeste ) => {
      document.querySelector("input#form-clientes").value = valorTeste;
},valorTeste).catch(error => { console.log(error) });
```

em alguns casos a pagina não reconhece a alteração feita com o evaluate,
pra fazer funcionar tu precisa fazer o change, uma maneira que eu uso muito é essa:

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
      $("input#form-clientes").trigger("change");
}).catch(error => { console.log(error) });
```